# How to use VBA to offset + one column when a specific criteria is met (Loop)

Tags: vba, excel

I've created a spreadsheet to calculate time study averages, in which trying to transfer specific information from one sheet to the other, while offsetting a column when a specific criteria is met. I was able to complete a code to retrieve the desired data (avg time) from sheet("Time_Study_Data_Analysis") to sheet("Process_Modeling_Tool"). But I was only able to get all the data to populate in one column.

I would like to offset +1 column after all the "activity tasks" have been populated for each "Process Element".. I will attach my spreadsheet for better clarification, or I can send it via email. Any help will be greatly appreciated. Please contact me if you need further detail. Thank you

```
Sub Time_Study()
    Rn = 17
    Rn2 = 8

    Do Until Sheets("Time_Study_Data_Analysis").Cells(Rn, 2) = "HARTNESS"
        If Sheets("Time_Study_Data_Analysis").Cells(Rn, 3) = Empty Then
            Rn = Rn + 1
        Else
            Sheets("Process_Modeling_Tool").Cells(Rn2, 2) = Sheets("Time_Study_Data_Analysis").Cells(Rn, 3)
            Sheets("Process_Modeling_Tool").Cells(Rn2, 6) = Sheets("Time_Study_Data_Analysis").Cells(Rn, 14)
            Rn = Rn + 1
            Rn2 = Rn2 + 1
        End If
    Loop
End Sub
```

[image: SCREENSHOT OF OBJECTIVE]

Comment: Can you post the example of your spreadsheet?

Comment: Hello Rob G. I can email you the spreadsheet if you like. Maybe looking at it you will get a better understanding of what I'm trying to accomplish. Thanks for your help..

Comment: If you can post a screen shot of a simplified version that would be better, then other people can help you too.

Comment: I've inserted a screenshot. Please advise if it was helpful

Comment: Maybe I'm missing something, but wouldn't this be simpler to use formulas in the second worksheet linked to the first? It seems that they will always be pulled from the same cells, wouldn't they? if you needed them 'frozen' as a report at a point in time, you could have a macro that calculated, then did a copy/paste as values.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should do it

```
Sub Time_Study()
    Dim rn As Long, rn2 As Long, cl As Long
    rn = 17
    rn2 = 8
    cl = 6 ' if the outpout is off the correct column adjust this.

    Do Until Sheets("Time_Study_Data_Analysis").Cells(rn, 2) = "HARTNESS"
        If Sheets("Time_Study_Data_Analysis").Cells(rn, 3) <> "" And _
            Sheets("Time_Study_Data_Analysis").Cells(rn - 1, 3) = "" Then
                cl = cl + 1
        End If
        If Sheets("Time_Study_Data_Analysis").Cells(rn, 3) = "" Then
            rn = rn + 1
        Else
            Sheets("Process_Modeling_Tool").Cells(rn2, 2) = Sheets("Time_Study_Data_Analysis").Cells(rn, 3)
            Sheets("Process_Modeling_Tool").Cells(rn2, cl) = Sheets("Time_Study_Data_Analysis").Cells(rn, 14)
            rn = rn + 1
            rn2 = rn2 + 1
        End If
    Loop
End Sub
```

Every time a new group is found it will move over a column.  The new group is decided from a full cell preceded by an empty.

I also declared the variables, this is important if your row exceed the integer limit.

---

As a side note, using the With Block will save a lot of repetitious typing, and shorten some of the longer lines:

```
Sub Time_Study()
    Dim rn As Long, rn2 As Long, cl As Long
    rn = 17
    rn2 = 8
    cl = 6 ' if the outpout is off the correct column adjust this.
    With Sheets("Time_Study_Data_Analysis")
        Do Until .Cells(rn, 2) = "HARTNESS"
            If .Cells(rn, 3) <> "" And .Cells(rn - 1, 3) = "" Then
                    cl = cl + 1
            End If
            If .Cells(rn, 3) = "" Then
                rn = rn + 1
            Else
                Sheets("Process_Modeling_Tool").Cells(rn2, 2) = .Cells(rn, 3)
                Sheets("Process_Modeling_Tool").Cells(rn2, cl) = .Cells(rn, 14)
                rn = rn + 1
                rn2 = rn2 + 1
            End If
        Loop
    End With
End Sub
```

Comment: Your solutions are always simple and elegant.